# Find only unique number in vector

Tags: c++, vectors

Find the number occuring only once in a vector.
Given a vector A, containing N pairs (1, 1, 2, 3, 3 ... etc.) and one unique number, find and return the one unique number.

I wrote the following code for this problem.

As I don't have a lot of experience I would be grateful for any kind of feedback regarding my solution so it can be improved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

uint32_t find_unique(std::vector<uint32_t> &A)
{
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, uint32_t> seen;

    for (const auto &it : A)
    {
        if (++seen[it] > 1)
        {
            seen.erase(it);
        }
    }

    return seen.begin()->first;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint32_t> v{1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5};

    std::cout << find_unique(v) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Loki, the question states "*N* pairs" and one unique member.  If I'd read only the title, I'd have agreed with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a more efficient algorithm. It's clear that the unique value is equal to the xor of all numbers in the vector. One can write a nice one-liner to compute it:

```
std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), (uint32_t)0, [](uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return a ^ b; })
```

The time complexity is the same (as a hash table works in `O(1)` on average), but this code is likely to work faster in practice. It also requires `O(1)` extra memory, while your solution needs `O(n)`, so it's more space efficient.

I'd also say that your code is little bit confusing (it inserts keys implicitly via `[]` operator but erases them explicitly). It took me a while to figure out what's going on. I think that the solution with a set is a little bit more clear as it makes all insertions and deletions explicitly:

```
unordered_set<uint32_t> seen;
for (const auto& elem : v) {
     if (seen.count(elem))
         seen.erase(elem);
     else
         seen.insert(elem);
}
return *seen->begin();
```

You can also omit `return 0` in the main function (it returns 0 by default, anyway).

Comment: The part about `"\n"` seems wrong. `std::endl` includes a flush of the stream which is nearly always unnecessary.

Comment: @miscco You're right, it doesn't localize the line separator, so it's useless. I removed this part of my answer.

Comment: @kraskevich: Just for reference. The `'\n'` character is also converted to platform specific line termination sequence.

Comment: @LokiAstari The post says that all other numbers form pairs, which is the same thing as an even number of occurrences.

Comment: The XOR solution is pretty nifty.